Lenovo Legion Y740 with 2070 Max Q Built in display Flickering
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 in my Y740 Intel I7-9750H with 2070 MaxQ and the Nvidia Drivers 535 version is installed. I am having issues with where My Laptop built in display is flickering though. I have connected an external display thought the thunderbolt port and that works fine . Kindly help me fix this problem.
This does not happen in Windows. And The only way i was able to install Ubuntu in the first place is via the safe graphics option in the bootable USB. The regular Try it out and install also had the problem.
The built in display is 1920x1280 144hz and G-Sync Capable. If it is relevant.

Why that driver? What is the video card chips set?

That was the latest version available in Ubuntu. I have tried many drivers but None of them seem to fix this. I only know that it is a NVIDIA RTX 2070 Max Q. It is a laptop LENOVO Legion y740
